# Get Upload File in Update Yii

Tags: image, upload, yii

I have a project that incorporates a form, a field is to upload an image and want to update an item when a warning appears saying "Img Cover cannot be blank.". But I want the field to upload the image to continue with the upload previously created.
Have googled but without success.

Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Not too sure to understand what you want, but you can look at this resources in Yii wiki:

- [Saving files to a blob field in the database](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/95/saving-files-to-a-blob-field-in-the-database/)
- [How to upload a file using a model](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/2/how-to-upload-a-file-using-a-model/)
- [File uploads in CForm (Form Builder)](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/265/file-uploads-in-cform-form-builder/)

Usually, you have to make your checks in model's `beforeSave()` method, something like this, for an `image` field you want to save but checking you are not in an `update` scenario (you have to set the scenario yourself).

```
public function beforeSave()
{
   if ($image = CUploadedFile::getInstance($this, 'image')) {
     $this->image = file_get_contents($image->tempName);
   }
   if ($this->scenario == 'update' && !$this->image) {
      unset($this->image);
   }
   return parent::beforeSave();
}
```

Comment: @ sandro Ferraz could you post your solved answer..i too have the same problem.....